# Correct addressing in REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I create an application where you can ask questions and answers. I have a small problem with the decision on how to create an address to add an assessment for the answer to the question.

Two ideas come to me

```
POST http://localhost:8080/answers/{answerId}/votes
```

or

```
POST http://localhost:8080/questions/{questionId}/answers/{answerId}/votes
```

It seems to me that the first address fits better because on the site I will be able to get the answer

```
AnswerEntity answerEntity = this.answerRepository.getById(answerId);
answerEntity.setVotes(...);
```

However, the service for the second address would look like this

```
QuestionEntity questionEntity = this.questionRepository.getById(questionId);
for(AnswerEntity answer : questionEntity .getAnswers()) {
     if(answer.getId().equals(answerId) [
          answerEntity = answer;
     }
}
answerEntity.setVotes(...);
```

Therefore, it seems to me that the first address is better, but I would like to ask you for an opinion on this subject. Is the first address correct syntax according to the REST API?

Comment: Since `answerId` is presumably unique, use that.

Comment: Do you mean the first address? Is the first address correct syntax according to the REST API?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I do not know and ask you. So there is no problem for me to use the first address to rate the answer?

Comment: I would use the 2nd URL since it's semantically clearer, but I don't see why you can't still use a globally unique `answerId` and use `this.answerRepository.getById(answerId);` since you still have `{answerId}` in your 2nd URL.

Comment: If I use the second address, the `questionId` will be unused because I get the answer according to `answerId`.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Questions which are [primarily opinion based are off topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Explicitly asking for opinions is nearly always a sign that the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both paths are valid for a REST API but they have different semantics.

The first path `/answers/{answerId}/votes` should allow access to votes of an arbitrary answer in your system by simply using the unique answer ID as a reference. There is no question context here.

The second path `/questions/{questionId}/answers/{answerId}/votes` limits the set of answer IDs which are valid to use in the URL because the beginning of that path narrows the context to a particular question. Then only answer IDs for that specific question should be allowed to request the respective votes.

So it depends on what you want to provide for your consumers, i.e. what suits best your consumer's needs.

Comment: To get the answer from the database I only need a `answerId`. Therefore, the `questionId` in the second address will not be used at all. So why why the `questionId` in the second address?

Comment: It's about what semantic you want to provide with the REST API. Of course, you can load an answer by its unique ID from the database but is that really what you want to offer as an API to the consumers? If you want to follow domain-driven design the second path is more logical because an answer cannot exist without a question, right? And if you want to make sure that the API contrains the consumers to only access votes for answers of the questions they belong to then you should go for the second path.